# Dropdown list bound to object data source - how to update on a button click

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

This is probably something really stupidly simple..

I have a drop down list bound to an object data source.  I have set AppendDataBoundItems to true so that I can have an initial select.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Accommodations1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="AccommodationTypeDescription" DataValueField="Id" OnDataBound="Accommodations1_DataBound" onSelectedIndexChanged="Accommodations1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="200px" DataSourceID="AccommodationDs" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
       <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="AccommodationDs" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="ListByPropertyId" TypeName="PropertyAccommodationController">
      <SelectParameters>
           <asp:Parameter Name="PropertyId" Type="Int32" />
      </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I have a button which adds an accommodaton - so after that happens I need the dropdown list to update to include the new accommodation. So I've tried calling databind on the dropdownlist, and databind on the datasource - and nothing is making this dropdown list update.

eg.  PropertyAccommodations1.DataBind();

Could someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong.  Originally I thought it was due to an update panel issue.. but I've removed the update panel and it still doesn't work (and checked the master page doesn't include an update panel).

Thanks!!

Comment: I removed the AppendDataItems true - and call data bind in the dropdownlist and it updates as expected.  

How do I have a drop down list with a "Select" default value - without having these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the quick responses - have implemented

```
Accommodations1.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("Select",""));
```

as I specifically wanted it at the top :)

I still think it would be neater to have this default item in the source of the page - but that AppendDataItems is tripping me up.

Comment: @alejandrobog: I disagree with your statement. Jen has specifically added a different line of code and modified it to be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can subrcibe to DDL OnDataBound and add the "Select" item

```
Accommodations1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select",""));
```

Comment: Thanks!  I figure this will be the way I go - but I would have liked to have had the default item in the source of the page, and then just appended the items - seemed a nice way of doing it :)

Comment: There can be issues if you set AppendDataBoundItems="true", for example if call databind again your items would be duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

In the button click, after you call .DataBind() on the DDL, you can then do

```
Accommodations1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select"));
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to do it in code - but thanks :) 

If I do have to do it in code I'll also need to add it after the initial bind - where's the best place to do this.

ie. currently on page load I set this: 
 AccommodationDs.SelectParameters["propertyId"].DefaultValue = ((int)Master.PropertyId).ToString();

Which is the datasource that the dropdownlist is bound to.  I don't specifically call databind on the dropdownlist when the page is loading - so where would I put the add? Or should I be calling the dropdownlist databind after setting the select parameter of datasource?