# dropdown not choosing the correct item

Tags: asp.net

I am using asp.net and vb.net as code behind. I have dropdown box. It will populate the list of values on page load. I have a data coming from webservice. arrdata consists of web service data.

```
If IsNothing(arrData(12)) Then
  DropDownList_mylist.Items.Add(New ListItem("Choose"))
  DropDownList_mylist.SelectedIndex = DropDownList_mylist.Items.IndexOf(DropDownList_mylist.Items.FindByText("Choose"))
Else
  DropDownList_mylist.SelectedIndex = DropDownList_mylist.Items.IndexOf(DropDownList_mylist.Items.FindByText(arrData(12)))
End If
```

The problem is, it is giving the first item. not the correct item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the AppendDataBoundItems property and set it to true if there are existing items in the list already.

Similar question here:

[Dropdown list bound to object data source - how to update on a button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963255/dropdown-list-bound-to-object-data-source-how-to-update-on-a-button-click)